# Появляется ошибка 553 Can't open that file: Permission denied в phpstorm

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu, phpstorm

Я использую php laravel. К серверу от имени пользователя root я подключаюсь в phpstorm, чтобы удобно было работать с консолью ubuntu. Но при создании, например, контроллера с использованием artisan и его дальнейшего изменения/выгрузки у меня появляется ошибка:
"Failed to transfer file" '\app\Http\Controllers\ProfessorsController.php'. Cant open output connection for file "ftp://123.123.123.123/app/Http/Controllers/ProfessorsController.php". Reason: "553 Can't open that file: Permission denied". Как ее можно исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему созданием нового пользователя с правами root. Под этим пользователем подключился к консоли в phpstorm и подключился к ftp через phpstorm. Далее изменил права в своем каталоге командой, где www-data это имя нового пользователя и html это имя каталога, в котором лежит проект

```
sudo chown -Rf www-data:www-data /var/www/html/*
```

Comment: Ты же в курсе, я надеюсь, что гонять трафик по чистому ftp в 21-м веке немного неправильно?

Comment: @donRumata нет, я не разбираюсь в этом. Просвети, если не сложно

Comment: В общем в ванильном исполнении, фтп НЕ использует шифрование. А значит все файлы, все логины и пароли, которые ты кидаешь по этому протоколу - можно перехватить где-то по пути. Если тебе инфа неважна или ты её и так выставляешь на всеобщее обозрение - проблем нет. Если есть хоть какая-то секретная часть - лучше прочитай про `ssh+sftp`.

Comment: Про фтп уже сказали, а еще хорошо бы от использования root отказаться. Если нужна консоль под root, то в Phpstorm можно настроить несколько соединений для консоли и разных и к разным серверам и как с глобальной видимостью и также только для проекта. Сайт редактировать под обычным пользователем через ssh/sftp, а уж понадобились root права что поменять, то подключаетесь в консоли и делаете.